# Rootbeer GPU CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY

Tags: java, gpu, rootbeer

I have been trying to work with this GPU library `Rootbeer` I have run the demos, and they run fine, I then try to run my code, and on the second to last line of this snippet (`Rootbeer rootbeer = new Rootbeer();`), I get an error (see last section).

```
    // This sesction is within a JSlider change event.
    int val = sldBrightness.getValue();
    List<Kernel> jobs = new ArrayList<Kernel>();
    jobs.add(new Brightness(val));
    Rootbeer rootbeer = new Rootbeer();
    rootbeer.runAll(jobs);
```

Here is the class that I am running:

```
package pocketshop.graphics.adjustments;

import edu.syr.pcpratts.rootbeer.runtime.Kernel;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import pocketshop.Canvas;
import pocketshop.graphics.Colors;
import pocketshop.graphics.Preview;

/**
 *
 * @author Ryan
 */
public class Brightness implements Kernel {

    protected int amount = 0;
    protected int width, height;
    int[] pixels; // = new int[width * height];

    public void amount(int amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public Brightness(int amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
        width = Canvas.image.getWidth();
        height = Canvas.image.getHeight();
        pixels = new int[width * height];
        Canvas.image.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, pixels, 0, width);
    }

    public void setImage() {
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        img.setRGB(0, 0, width, height, pixels, 0, width);
        Preview.setImage(img);
    }

    @Override
    public void gpuMethod() {
        int[] pixels = this.pixels;
        for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
            int pixel = pixels[i];
            int red = Colors.red(pixel);
            int green = Colors.green(pixel);
            int blue = Colors.blue(pixel);

            red += amount;
            if (red > 255) {
                red = 255;
            } else if (red < 0) {
                red = 0;
            }

            green += amount;
            if (green > 255) {
                green = 255;
            } else if (green < 0) {
                green = 0;
            }

            blue += amount;
            if (blue > 255) {
                blue = 255;
            } else if (blue < 0) {
                blue = 0;
            }
            pixels[i] = Colors.rgba(red, green, blue);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the output error. I am really stumped as to why this is showing `Caused by: edu.syr.pcpratts.rootbeer.runtime2.cuda.CudaErrorException: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: gpuHandlesMemory memory allocation failed`

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at edu.syr.pcpratts.rootbeer.runtime.RootbeerFactory.create(RootbeerFactory.java:19)
    at edu.syr.pcpratts.rootbeer.runtime.Rootbeer.<init>(Rootbeer.java:19)
    at pocketshop.dialogs.BrightnessContrastDialog.sldBrightnessStateChanged(BrightnessContrastDialog.java:191)
    at pocketshop.dialogs.BrightnessContrastDialog.access$100(BrightnessContrastDialog.java:21)
    at pocketshop.dialogs.BrightnessContrastDialog$2.stateChanged(BrightnessContrastDialog.java:65)
    at javax.swing.JSlider.fireStateChanged(JSlider.java:432)
    at javax.swing.JSlider$ModelListener.stateChanged(JSlider.java:350)
    at javax.swing.DefaultBoundedRangeModel.fireStateChanged(DefaultBoundedRangeModel.java:364)
    at javax.swing.DefaultBoundedRangeModel.setRangeProperties(DefaultBoundedRangeModel.java:302)
    at javax.swing.DefaultBoundedRangeModel.setValue(DefaultBoundedRangeModel.java:168)
    at javax.swing.JSlider.setValue(JSlider.java:531)
    at pocketshop.dialogs.BrightnessContrastDialog.txtBrightnessActionPerformed(BrightnessContrastDialog.java:180)
    at pocketshop.dialogs.BrightnessContrastDialog.access$300(BrightnessContrastDialog.java:21)
    at pocketshop.dialogs.BrightnessContrastDialog$4.actionPerformed(BrightnessContrastDialog.java:88)
    at javax.swing.JTextField.fireActionPerformed(JTextField.java:508)
    at javax.swing.JTextField.postActionEvent(JTextField.java:721)
    at javax.swing.JTextField$NotifyAction.actionPerformed(JTextField.java:836)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.notifyAction(SwingUtilities.java:1664)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBinding(JComponent.java:2879)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(JComponent.java:2926)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2842)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6282)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1895)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:762)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1027)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:899)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:727)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4731)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:723)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:696)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:693)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:155)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:182)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:221)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:219)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1077)
    at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1651)
    at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1603)
    at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1014)
    at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1003)
    at pocketshop.Main.jMenuItem4ActionPerformed(Main.java:233)
    at pocketshop.Main.access$200(Main.java:15)
    at pocketshop.Main$3.actionPerformed(Main.java:180)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:877)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:723)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:696)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:693)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
Caused by: edu.syr.pcpratts.rootbeer.runtime2.cuda.CudaErrorException: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: gpuHandlesMemory memory allocation failed
    at edu.syr.pcpratts.rootbeer.runtime2.cuda.CudaRuntime2.setup(Native Method)
    at edu.syr.pcpratts.rootbeer.runtime2.cuda.CudaRuntime2.<init>(CudaRuntime2.java:92)
    at edu.syr.pcpratts.rootbeer.runtime2.cuda.CudaRuntime2.v(CudaRuntime2.java:38)
    at edu.syr.pcpratts.rootbeer.runtime.ConcreteRootbeer.<init>(ConcreteRootbeer.java:27)
    ... 105 more
```

Comment: What is your GPU? How much memory your code do allocate on GPU?

Comment: I have an evga GeForce 9500 GT. With rootbeer I don't know how to allocate memory on the GPU the examples it didn't show how. Here is one of the examples: https://github.com/pcpratts/rootbeer1/tree/master/examples/ArraySumApp/src/rootbeer/examples/arraysum

Comment: Hi, can you please have a look at the below URL regarding the rootbeer, and give me some support? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22597183/unable-to-cast-a-class-error

Answer (score 1):

Try to edit the file: /.rootbeer/config

Change the reserve_mem value to be a larger number.

Then could email me the results of this command:
$ java -jar Rootbeer.jar -printdeviceinfo